# A question about $n$ points in the real plane, and a polynomial that passes through them.

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have $n$ points on the real plane ($n \geq 1$), such that no two of them have the same $x$-coordinate, in other words, the set of points passes the "vertical line test" for functions. Does there exist a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n-1$ that goes through those points, and if so, is the polynomial $p$ unique among polynomials of degree at most $n-1$? Note, the identically $0$ function has degree $-\infty$, and so is also of degree at most $0$.

Comment: Isn't this the Lagrange interpolation polynomial? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial 

The same may also be derived using Newton's forward difference formula. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html

Comment: I believe the forward difference formula only works when the $x$-coordinates are in arithmetic progression. But yes, Lagrange interpolation is 100% what the OP wants to know.

Comment: Well, I want a proof of existence and uniqueness of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $n-1$ degree polinomial can be written as
$$a_{(n-1)} x^{(n-1)}+a_{(n-2)}x^{(n-2)}+\dots+a_1x+a_0=y$$

Meaning that every time you replace the x-y coordinates of a point on the curve, you get an equation with $n$ unknown.
For the curve to pass through all the $n$ points then it should satisfy all the $n$ equations Simultaneously.
So finding the curve is essentially solving a system of $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns.

So we can deduce

1. if a solution exists, it is unique.
2. a solution does not exist then the determinant below has to be zero which is not possible if all $x$ are different
   $$\left\vert
   \begin{cases}
   1 & x_1    & x_1^2  & \dots  & x_1^{(n-1)} \\
   1 & x_2    & x_2^2  & \dots  & x_2^{(n-1)} \\
   1 & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots      \\
   1 & x_n    & x_n^2  & \dots  & x_n^{(n-1)}
   \end{cases}
   \right\vert$$